# Regex allow empty string in my current expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to allow an empty string or null string in my regular expression:

```
^[0-9][0-9]*
```

what should I add to achieve this, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Probably, you just want:

```
^[0-9]*
```

As is, you have a non-optional character class which means no empty string will match.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the first digit:

```
^[0-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `|` as 'or', so in this following regex, it is either empty, or [0-9]+

```
(|^[0-9][0-9]*)
```

Also, `[0-9][0-9]*` can be simplified to `[0-9]+` -- they are the same.

However, in this particular case, you can probably just do:

```
^[0-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

this?:

```
^[\s\d]*
```

Match : "123" abc in "123 abc"

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check to see if a string is empty? (as in only has whitespace) If so `^\w*$` would match such a string.

Also, you mentioned a null string. Depending on what language you're using, passing a NULL pointer to a regex function may result in a segfault.

Comment: `\w` matches a word character, i.e., `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.  The shorthand for whitespace is `\s`.